# Size of int on 8-bit machines

Tags: c, int, sizeof, 8-bit

The ISO C standard states that `A "plain" int object has the natural size suggested by the architecture of the execution environment`

However, it is also guaranteed that int is at least as large as short, which is at least 16 bits in size.

The natural size suggested by an 8-bit processor, such as a 6502 or 8080, would seem to be an 8-bit int, however that would make int shorter than 16 bits.
So, how large would int be on one of these 8 bit processors?

Comment: C and C++ guarantee that `sizeof(char) <= sizeof(short) <= sizeof(int) <= sizeof(long) <= sizeof(long long)`, so an `int` can never be smaller than a `short`, even if the "natural" size would be otherwise.  C++ guarantees that `short` is at least 16 bits.  Not sure if C makes the same guarantee.

Comment: Section 5.2.4.2.1 of N1548: `SHRT_MAX` and `INT_MAX` must be at least `32767`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From [Section 6.2.5 Types, p5](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.2.5p5)

> 5 An object declared as type signed char occupies the same amount of storage as a ''plain'' char object. A ''plain'' int object has the natural size suggested by the architecture of the execution environment (large enough to contain any value in the range INT_MIN to INT_MAX as defined in the header `<limits.h>`).

And [5.2.4.2.1 Sizes of integer types <limits.h> p1](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#5.2.4.2.1p1)

> Their implementation-defined values shall be equal or greater in magnitude (absolute value) to those shown, with the same sign.
>
> ...
>
> - minimum value for an object of type int
>
>   INT_MIN                                -32767 // -(2<sup>15</sup> - 1)
> - maximum value for an object of type int
>
>   INT_MAX                                +32767 // 2<sup>15</sup> - 1

Then in those platforms, `int` must be at least 16 bits

Comment: In practice, however, some might use 8-bit `int`: `avr-gcc` has `-mint8` switch for that.

Answer (score 4):

The 6502 had only the instruction pointer as 16 bit register, the 16 bit integers were handled with 8 bits with multiple statements, e.g. if you do in 16 bits `c = a + b`

```
clc                 ; clear carry bit
lda A_lo            ; lower byte of A into accumulator
adc B_lo            ; add lower byte of B to accumulator, put carry to carry bit
sta C_lo            ; store the result to lower byte of C
lda A_hi            ; higher byte of A into accumulator
adc B_hi            ; add higher byte of B using carry bit
sta C_hi            ; store the result to higher byte of C
```

8080 and Z80 CPUs at that time had 16 bit registers as well.

The Z80 CPU was still 8 bit architecture. It's 16 bit registers were eventually pairing two 8 bit registers, like BC, DE. The operations with them were much slower then with 8 bit registers because the CPU architecture was 8 bit, but this way 16 bit registers and 16 operations were provided.

8088 architecture was mixed, because it also had 8 bit data bus, but it had 16 bit registers, AX, BX, etc., lower and higher bytes also separately usably as 8 bit registers, AL, AH, etc.

So there were different solutions to use 16 bit integers but 8 bit is simply not a useful integer. That's why C and C++ used also 16 bit for int.

Comment: I used to work with an Introl-C compiler on a 6809 (8-bit) architecture and `sizeof(int)` was 16 bits. 6809 also had internal 16 bits registers.

Comment: The 6502 definitely did not have any 16 bit registers. You had 8-bit A, 8-bit X, and 8-bit Y. Even the stack pointer was 8 bits. You could argue the instruction pointer was 16 bit, but it was inaccessible and _the instruction pointer_